# python print jinja2 rendered output in json format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jinja2

my variable file/data (i get this info from other source)

final_lst:

```
[
  {
    "service_role": "do_not_use",
    "first_ip": "10.7.17.1",
    "last_ip": "10.7.16.9",
    "uid": "do_not_use"
  },
  {
    "service_role": "role_a",
    "first_ip": "10.7.17.10",
    "last_ip": "10.7.17.25",
    "uid": "role_a_range_01"
  },
  {
    "service_role": "role_a",
    "first_ip": "10.7.17.56",
    "last_ip": "10.7.17.70",
    "uid": "role_a_range_02"
  }
]
```

test.j2:

```
{%- for item in final_lst %}
sr: {{item.service_role}}
ip: {{item.first_ip}}
{%- endfor -%}
```

my code:
from jinja2 import Template , Environment, FileSystemLoader

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'),)
int_template = env.get_template('test.j2')     

out = int_template.render(final_lst=final_lst)
print(out)
```

result:

```
sr: do_not_use
ip: 10.7.17.1
sr: role_a
fip: 10.7.17.10
sr: role_a
fip: 10.7.17.56
```

what i want to print is in json format like below

desired output:

```
[
  {
    "sr": "do_not_use",
    "fip": "10.7.17.1"
  },
  {
    "sr": "role_a",
    "fip": "10.7.17.10"
  },
  {
    "sr": "role_a",
    "fip": "10.7.17.56"
  }
]
```

i have a requirement to generate above output via jinja2 template. how can i get json format output anything that is rendered from jinja2 template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest **not** to generate json with means of template language. It is slower and much more error prone.

In your python code:

```py
import json
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader

data = [
  {
    "service_role": "do_not_use",
    "first_ip": "10.7.17.1",
    "last_ip": "10.7.16.9",
    "uid": "do_not_use"
  },
  {
    "service_role": "role_a",
    "first_ip": "10.7.17.10",
    "last_ip": "10.7.17.25",
    "uid": "role_a_range_01"
  },
  {
    "service_role": "role_a",
    "first_ip": "10.7.17.56",
    "last_ip": "10.7.17.70",
    "uid": "role_a_range_02"
  }
]
data = [
    {
        'sr': elem['service_role'],
        'fip': elem['first_ip'],
    }
    for elem in data
]
data_dump = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'),)
int_template = env.get_template('test.j2')     

out = int_template.render(data_dump=data_dump)
print(out)
```

In your template (`test.j2`):

```
{{ data_dump }}
```

## Don't do this!

If you insist on template solution:

```
[
  {% for item in final_lst %}
  {{ '{' }}
    "sr": "{{ item.service_role }}",
    "ip": "{{ item.first_ip }}"
  {{ '}' }}
  {% endfor %}
]
```

You can replace `{%` with `{%-` back to get compact representation (same applies to `json.dumps`, just get rid of `indent` parameter).

Comment: Thank you, worked., your suggestion is taken